# Como fazer para não permitir digitar números repetidos com angular

Tags: angularjs

Como faço para não permitir digitar números repetidos na validação? Na minha atual validação, consigo deixar obrigatorio o preenchimento dos campos para habilitar o botão salvar e nesse input tarefaSelecionada.ordemTarefa, só permito validar o botão digitando números, mas é possível adicionar essa condição de não permitir repetir numeros nessa lista na validação?

```js
//validação
$scope.exibeValidacaoTarefa = function() {
  for (var tarefa in $scope.tarefasSelecionadas) {
    if ($scope.tarefasSelecionadas[tarefa].ordemTarefa == null ||
      $scope.tarefasSelecionadas[tarefa].ordemTarefa == "") {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return $scope.atividadeInput == null ||
    $scope.atividadeInput == "" ||
    $scope.atividadeInput.descAtividade == null ||
    $scope.atividadeInput.descAtividade == "" ||
    $scope.atividadeInput.solicitante == null ||
    $scope.atividadeInput.solicitante == "" ||
    $scope.tarefasSelecionadas == null;
}

$scope.exibeValidacaoEditarTarefa = function() {
    for (var tarefa in $scope.tarefasSelecionadas) {
      if ($scope.tarefasSelecionadas[tarefa].ordemTarefa == null ||
        $scope.tarefasSelecionadas[tarefa].ordemTarefa == "") {
        return true;
      }
    }


    //submit
    $scope.adicionarAtividade = function(atividadeInput) {
      var codigo = "";
      atividadesInput.codigoAtividade = codigo;
      atividadesInput.descAtividade = $scope.atividadeInput.descAtividade;
      atividadesInput.solicitante = $scope.atividadeInput.solicitante;

      atividadesInput.matrizJson = [];
      for (var int = 0; int < $scope.tarefasSelecionadas.length; int++) {
        var gride = {};
        gride.codTarefa = $scope.tarefasSelecionadas[int].codigo;
        gride.ordemTarefa = $scope.tarefasSelecionadas[int].ordemTarefa;
        atividadesInput.matrizJson.push(gride)
      }

      atividadesAPI.saveAtividade(atividadesInput).success(function(data) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#ModalAdicionaAtividadeSucesso").modal('show');
        });
        $scope.atividadeInput = {};
        $scope.tarefasSelecionadas = {};
        carregarTarefas();
        carregarAtividades();
      }).error(function(data, status) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#ModalAdicionaAtividadeErro").modal('show');
        });
        $scope.message = "Aconteceu um problema: " + data;
      });


    };
```

```html
<tr ng-repeat="tarefaSelecionada in tarefasSelecionadas">
  <td scope="row">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="numbers" ng-model="tarefaSelecionada.ordemTarefa" ng-required="true">
  </td>
</tr>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" ng-click="adicionarAtividade(atividadeInput)" data-dismiss="modal" id="btn-cadastra-atividade" onclick="atualiza()" ng-disabled="exibeValidacaoTarefa()">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> Salvar
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Aqui uma pequena função para verificar se foi digitado uma letra/número repetido, adapte conforme a sua necessidade.

```js
    var arr = [];
    function verificaDigitios(e) {
        var keynum;

        if (window.event) { // IE                    
            keynum = e.keyCode;
        } else if (e.which) { // Netscape/Firefox/Opera                   
            keynum = e.which;
        }
        var digito = String.fromCharCode(keynum);
        if (arr.includes(digito)) {
            alert("NÃO É PERMITIDO DIGITOS REPETIDOS!")
            return false;
        } else {
            arr.push(digito)
        }
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeypress="return verificaDigitios(event)" />
```

**Código para checar se o valor já foi informado em outro campo.**

> O código abaixo verifica se o valor já foi informado em outro input,
>   **importante** informar uma **id** para cada campo.

```js
$(document).on("change", "input[type='text']", function() {
  var campoAtual = $(this);
    $("input[type='text']").each(function(){
      var input = $(this);
      if (campoAtual.attr('id') !== input.attr('id') && campoAtual.val() !== "") {
        if (campoAtual.val() === input.val()) {
          alert("NÃO PODE CONTER NÚMERO IGUAL, INFORME OUTRO.");
          campoAtual.val('');
          campoAtual.focus();
          return false;
        }
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1">
    <p>
      #1 - Informe um número:<br />
      <input type="text" id="1" value="1" />
    </p>
    <p>
      #2 - Informe um número:<br />
      <input type="text" id="2" value="2" />
    </p>
    <p>
      #3 - Informe um número:<br />
      <input type="text" id="3" value="3" />
    </p>
    <p>
      #4 - Informe um número:<br />
      <input type="text" id="4" value="4" />
    </p>
    <p>
      #5 - Informe um número:<br />
      <input type="text" id="5" value="5" />
    </p>
  </form>
```

Comment: Eu acho que não fui muito clara, a verificação não é não poder repetir no mesmo input, é ter uma lista de input e neles não ser possível digitar o mesmo número, pq essa lista é uma lista de ordenação, não pode repetir, por exemplo não posso digitar o numero 3 em um input e no outro digitar novamente o 3

Comment: @Isa verifique se é isso que precisa? Adapta conforme sua necessidade.